# Using gsub and regex to replace every other occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I am designing a card game (spades). I want to store each hand as a hash.

This is a randomly generated string representing a single had with 13 cards where `10c` is the key and `10` is the value

`"10c 10 bj 18 2s 15 3s 3 8d 8 as 14 kh 13 8c 8 3c 3 6d 6 kc 13 5d 5 ad 14"`

I want to replace the space `' '` between `10c` and `10` with a `=>` and the following space between `10` and `bj` with a comma... This shoulod look like `10c=>10,bj=>18` etc.

From there I will convert this to a hash by calling Hash#inspect; however, I haven't been able to find a way to replace the nth character of a string using gsub.

I've tried calling `hand.gsub(' ', '=>')` but this obviously replaces every instance of a space with  `=>`

Comment: `str.split.each_slice(2).to_h`

Comment: this works as well.

Comment: Your objective is to create a hash. One way to do that is to use a regular expression in one step (though I don't know how `gsub` fits it). That is not the only way, however, and in my opinion it is not the best way. By framing the question as you have you are unnecessarily limiting the approaches that can be used. This is sometimes referred to as an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @sawa how do you replace the nth character of a string using gsub?

Comment: @kel.o The answer for this original request is `s.gsub(/([^ ]* [^ ]*) /, '\1,').gsub(' ', '=>')`.

Comment: kel.o, the character at index `n = 4` of the string `s = "balderdash"` can be replaced with `"X"` as follows: `s.sub(/\A.{#{n}}\K./,"X") #=> "baldXrdash"`, `\K` reads, "forget everything matched so far".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build the hash right away with

```
s = "10c 10 bj 18 2s 15 3s 3 8d 8 as 14 kh 13 8c 8 3c 3 6d 6 kc 13 5d 5 ad 14"
hash = Hash[s.scan(/(\w+) (\d+)/)].transform_values(&:to_i)
```

Or, for older Ruby versions:

```
hash = Hash[s.scan(/(\w+) (\d+)/)]
hash = Hash[ hash.map{ |a, b| [ a, b.to_i ] } ]
puts hash
# => {"10c"=>10, "bj"=>18, "2s"=>15, "3s"=>3, "8d"=>8, "as"=>14, "kh"=>13, "8c"=>8, "3c"=>3, "6d"=>6, "kc"=>13, "5d"=>5, "ad"=>14}
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/wuhBph)

The `(\w+) (\d+)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more word chars (with `(\w+)`, letters, digits or underscores, you may use `[[:alnum:]]+`, or `[^\W_]`, instead to match letters or digits), then matches a space, and then captures into Group 2 any one or more digits (`(\d+)`). `String#scan` matches all non-overlapping occurrences, and only returns captured substrings that are leveraged into a hash that is built dynamically.

Note that when you run `b.to_i`, you need no additional checks since `\d+` will only match digit substrings (and they are of length 2 in the input).

Comment: If the value must be converted to int, use `hash[key] = val.to_i`

Comment: ahh this makes a lot of sense. this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: A detail: the way you've written it makes it appear that `scan` is returning the hash. Consider adding the line `hash` at the end or replacing the first two with `s.scan(/(\w+) (\d+)/).each_with_object({}) do |(key, val),hash|`.

Comment: To avoid each do loop. Use another hash syntax `Hash[s.scan(/(\w+) (\d+)/)]`

Comment: @Dyaniyal, if `Hash::[]` is to be used isn't it simpler to write `Hash[*s.split]`, as I have done?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It depends on whether one needs to pre-validate the input. If the input is clean, yes, `Hash[*s.split]` is enough.

Comment: The use of the regex hardly does that. If `s = "a 1 b"` your method would happily disregard `"b"`. At least `Hash[*s.split]` would raise an exception. If the data is to be checked that should be a separate task.

Comment: Regex can do extraction and validation at the dame time. That is the beauty of regex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the use of a regular expression is the best way to create the hash. Instead, I suggest using the methods [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-split), [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i). If `s` is the string given in the example,

```
Hash[*s.split].transform_values(&:to_i)
  #=> {"10c"=>10, "bj"=>18, "2s"=>15, "3s"=>3, "8d"=>8,
  #    "as" =>14, "kh"=>13, "8c"=> 8, "3c"=>3, "6d"=>6,
  #    "kc" =>13, "5d"=> 5, "ad"=>14}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = s.split
  #=> ["10c", "10", "bj", ... , "14"] 
b = Hash[*a]
  #=> {"10c"=>"10", "bj"=>"18", "2s"=>"15", "3s"=>"3",
  #    "8d" => "8", "as"=>"14", "kh"=>"13", "8c"=>"8",
  #    "3c" => "3", "6d"=> "6", "kc"=>"13", "5d"=>"5",
  #    "ad" =>"14"} 
b.transform_values(&:to_i)
  #=> {"10c"=>10, "bj"=>18, "2s"=>15, "3s"=>3, "8d"=>8,
  #    "as" =>14, "kh"=>13, "8c"=> 8, "3c"=>3, "6d"=>6,
  #    "kc" =>13, "5d"=> 5, "ad"=>14}
```

The *splat* operator (`*`), causes `Hash[*a]` to be evaluated as `Hash["10c", "10", "bj", ... , "14"]`.

`b.transform_values(&:to_i)` is here equivalent to `b.transform_values { |v| v.to_i }`.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `transform_values(&:to_i)` line? It seems that splitting the string and calling the splat operator on the new array are sufficient.

Comment: @kel.o, The question requires that the values be integers, not strings. I made a small change to my answer that replaces the possibly ambiguous line `#=> (the hash given above)` with  the hash that is returned.